# why where clause only works for the one flied in SQL?

Tags: mysql

**Problem:**

I have created a table in SQL using phpmyadmin. It has four field user_id, username, password,usertype. Then I inserted data to that table. But when I run a SQL query to get a user like this `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = tharinduS`.But this works only when I use user_id = 1 instead of username = tharinduS. But username tharinduS exists in the table. I tried a lot to figure it out what's wrong with this. But I was unable to do so. Can you please someone help me to figure this out?. Thank you.

Comment: A string value like `tharinduS` needs to be enclosed in single quotes i.e. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'tharinduS'`

Comment: @Nick I do this with nodejs. so can you help me it with this command. `sql.query(
    'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '+username,callback
    )`

Comment: `sql.query( 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = \''+username + '\'',callback )`